# List Complexity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, declare

I have totally understed the lists but I have one more thing that I need to know before I am down with it
I have created to lists one with string and one with int

> The first string name is jack and its value is 2 The Second string 
>   name is john and its values is 5             But as result I am taking
>   John's value 2           John's value 5
>   Jack's value 2              Jack's value 5

How to make the first string to have only one value and the second its own

```
List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("Please insert a name ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        NameList.Add(name);

        List<int> answerList = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Please insert a value");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        answerList.Add(x);

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to calculate more ? (yes/no)");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        answer.Trim();

        bool isYes = true;
        while (isYes)
        {

            if (answer == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert another name/value");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                NameList.Add(name);
                answerList.Add(x);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to calculate more ? (yes/no)");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
                answer.Trim();
            }
            else if (answer == "no")
            { break; }
        } string are = " are ";
        foreach (var NAME in NameList)
        foreach (var item in answerList)

            Console.WriteLine("The values of " + NAME + are +item);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
foreach (var NAME in NameList)
foreach (var item in answerList)
```

you are doing a *cross join*, matching every name in `NameList` to every value in `answerList`.  You have a few options:

- Create a class that has `Name` and `Value` properties and store instances of that class in a single list
- Use the [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698.aspx) Linq function to line up the lists element-by-element and iterate through the results in a `foreach`

Other habits to get into now:

- Use consistent, standard capitalization.  Use camelCase for variables (e.g. `nameList`, `answerList`) and PascalCase for properties (`Name`, `Answer`).  Use ALL CAPS for *constant* values
- remember that `Trim` *returns* the trimmed string, so `answer.Trim()` does nothing (it throws away the output of `Trim`).  Use `answer = answer.Trim()` instead.

Comment: the Zip function seems the easier but how to apply

Comment: There are loads of documentation on MSDN and plenty of questions here to research.  Honestly, though, using a class would be a better approach.  Using `.Zip` would only be a better approach if you were joining lists from different sources that could not be combined.

Comment: thank you for everything but one more thing tell me the right thing to google for class because I have seen more about them and tried to mess with 'em but I hardly use them

Comment: I would search for `C# class`

Comment: I really cannot do that i created a class but as a result my second name overwrited the first
I really have stucked without foreach